# Какой выбрать драйвер для GT 620M В Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

Имею ноутбук Acer Aspire E1-571G с гибридной графикой (intel + nvidia optimus), с недавно установленной операционной системой Ubuntu 18.04.2.
`Linux 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Я хочу установить проприетарные драйвера для Nvidia и задействовать видеокарту по технологии PRIME.
Средства в операционной системе рекомендуют установить пакет `nvidia-340`:

```
:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001140sv00001025sd0000064Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (GeForce GT 620M)
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Но в родных репозиториях присутствует более новый драйвер `nvidia-driver-390` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/nvidia-driver-390.
В файле *README.TXT* который находится в данном пакете, в разделе "Appendix A. Supported NVIDIA GPU Products" присутствует моя видеокарта:

> `GeForce GT 620M                       1140 1025 064C     C`

И я не могу понять, почему мне не рекомедуют поставить более новую версию, может на это есть некие причины?

Вот информация о видеокартах:

```
:~$ lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1025:064b]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GeForce GT 620M [1025:064c]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Какую версию драйвера все же порекомендуете установить?
Спасибо.

Comment: Ставьте тот, который рекомендует Убунта. Есть вероятность, что его тестировали на совместимость с ОС. Потом, когда новый драйвер фирма протестирует на совместимость, переставите новый драйвер.

Comment: Я б ставил самый новый, а в случае проблем откатился. У меня очень старая видеокарта - gtx465 и 390й драйвер с ней работает без нареканий уже очень давно (в отличии от последних 418-430, с которыми ни иксы, ни вэйланд не запускаются).

Comment: Так там в комплекте идет уже три драйвера для nvidia, не считая nouveau!

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается недавно вышел новый 430 драйвер.Решил установить его. Получил такое сообщение в dmesg:

```
[   23.778869] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 620M GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 430.26 NVIDIA driver will ignore
               NVRM:  this GPU.  Continuing probe...
[   23.778872] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[   23.779863] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
```

Как я понял nvidia-driver-390 еще поддерживает мою видеокарту, 430 - уже нет. Установил 390.